# I am using following code in windows for checking live ports, it's working fine. But in ubuntu, no port is responding(result : 111)

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, ubuntu, networking, ports

```
import socket
ipaddr="127.0.0.1"
portlist=[22,23,80,100,135,912,135,445]
for port in portlist:
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    result=s.connect_ex((ipaddr,port))
    print port,':',result
    s.close()
```

Comment: Have you considered looking up what result 111 means?

Answer (score 0):

111 means ECONNREFUSED (connection refused). Check if you have these ports opened with an simple telnet on this.

But why do you use `socket.AF_INET6` and attrib an IPv4? Let's try to exchange to `socket.AF_INET`.